# Gnuplot: generate two different output files

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to print a chart. I want to print this chart once with a normal scale and once with a log scale.

When I print the image with a logscale I want to execute the following code:

```
set yrange[1:500]
set logscale y
set ytics (100, 200, 400) nomirror
```

However, when I want to print the image with a normal scale, I want to use the following code:

```
set yrange[1:350]
set ytics (100, 200, 300) nomirror
```

At the moment, I comment these command out if I want to print a specific version. However, I'm asking myself if there is a better option to do this. Maybe an if-condition?

The same question applies for the output file. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
set output '| ps2pdf - "plot.pdf"'
```

and if I print the log scale file, I just change the output name. However, I would prefer to generate both images at the same time. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
set terminal pdfcairo

set output 'normalPlot.pdf'

set yrange[1:350]
set ytics (100, 200, 300) nomirror
plot 'data.dat'

set output 'logPlot.pdf'

set yrange[1:500]
set logscale y
set ytics (100, 200, 400) nomirror
replot
```

It's fine to have two outputs at different points in the same script.

I also suggest using the `pdf` or `pdfcairo` terminals directly rather than converting, unless you have a good reason for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And also thank for the hint how I could generate two output files. However, no I have to duplicate my whole plot code. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, there is!  The `replot` command will plot the same data as the previous `plot` command.  (I meant to use that in my example the first time--I have edited it.)

Comment: cool thanks a lot! now I have to only figure out how to install pdfcairo on my mac and then everything is done :)

Comment: Ok another minor issue :) What if the last plot is a multiplot? :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException For multiplot mode you can't use `replot` but you could put the common code into one file and load it with `load 'file.gp'` from the main file.